# Xamarin Forms Teechart - chart.Zoomed doesn't work

Tags: xamarin.forms, teechart

I have a Xamarin Forms Application which display a Candle Teechart. I want to do some stuff when the user zooms and unzooms the chart. Just for testing purposes, I did the following thing:

```
tChart1.UndoneZoom += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        candleSeries.UpCloseColor = Color.Blue;
};

tChart1.Zoomed += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        candleSeries.UpCloseColor = Color.Pink;
};
```

When I zoom the chart, nothing happens, but when I double tap and unzoom it, the color changes to blue. Am I doing something wrong or is the .Zoomed event not working?

Comment: Does this occur with some specific platform (iOS, Android or Windows Phone) or happens in all of them? Thanks.

Comment: My test device is an Android. I haven't tried on other platforms yet.

Comment: I also tested it on the SampleProject which comes in the Steema folder in Program Files and it doesn't work either, so the problem is not in my project.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This is an Android bug. Please read my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the Zoomed event is not being fired in Android applications both with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Forms. I have added it as a defect ([bug #1287](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1287)) to be fixed for future releases. There's no workaround I can think of for now.

Comment: Do you think this will get fixed soon? I ask because depending on this we have to decide if we are going to buy the teechart for xamarin forms.

Comment: There are some prioritary tasks before but we will try to fix it ASAP. I'll get back to you with an update in a few days.

Comment: @IliaStoilov we have fixed the bug. You can download evaluation test assemblies at http://tinyurl.com/orzahb6

Comment: Thank you for the fast reaction. :)